# warden custom_failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, warden

I use devise for API authentication. I have overwritten `SessionController:create` method like this:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def create
    resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#new")
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
    val = sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    current_user.reset_authentication_token!

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        respond_with resource, :location => redirect_location(resource_name, resource)
      end
      format.json do
        render :json => { :status => OK_OK, :auth_token => current_user.authentication_token }.to_json, :status => :ok
      end
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see I respond with a status code when authenticating with JSON. When authentication fails I receive the following response:

```
{"error":"Invalid email or password."}
```

How do I change this message? I have no idea where to overwrite this `warden.authenticate!` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should implement your own failure app. You can look at and/or inherit from devise's default here
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/failure_app.rb

To set it up, in your config/initializers/devise.rb config file:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.warden do |manager|
    manager.failure_app = CustomFailureApp
  end
end
```

Comment: Hello polmiro. When I set `config.warden do |manager|
 manager.failure_app = CustomAuthFailure
end ` in the file above and restart the server I get an error message: `uninitialized constant CustomAuthFailure (NameError)`, although this is the name of my custom derivation of Devise::FailureApp in `lib/devise/custom_auth_failure.rb`. Any idea what I may have done wrong ? Thanks!

Comment: I added `config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib/devise')` in `config/application.rb` according to https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/Redirect-to-new-registration-(sign-up)-path-if-unauthenticated But now I still don't get into my custom FailureApp class when I issue wrong credentials in /sign_up ???

Comment: Don't put your CustomFailureApp inside /lib

Answer (score 1):

On your locale file (a file on config/locales/ directory), depending of your i18n configuration (for english it is `en.yml`) add this:

```
en:
  devise:
    invalid: 'My custom message for invalid login'
```

Of course, substitute `My custom message for invalid login` to the message you want.

Comment: Nope, that is not a solution. As you can see, I'm not interested in changing message itself but sending some codes I want. In example it was: `render :json => { :status => OK_OK, :auth_token => current_user.authentication_token }.to_json, :status => :ok` for correct authentication. For incorrect I want something like: `render :json => { :status => ERROR_AUTH }.to_json, :status => :unauthorized`.